# Unresolved external symbol error when calling functions in unzip class in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, windows, cocos2d-x

I am getting following linker errors while building my cocos2d-x win32 project on calls to functions in unzip class.

```
   1>ZipArchive.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void * __cdecl cocos2d::unzOpen(char const *)" (__imp_?unzOpen@cocos2d@@YAPAXPBD@Z)
1>ZipArchive.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl cocos2d::unzGetGlobalInfo(void *,struct cocos2d::unz_global_info_s *)" (__imp_?unzGetGlobalInfo@cocos2d@@YAHPAXPAUunz_global_info_s@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall myproject::ZipArchive::UnzipOpenFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?UnzipOpenFile@ZipArchive@myproject@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>ZipArchive.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl cocos2d::unzReadCurrentFile(void *,void *,unsigned int)" (__imp_?unzReadCurrentFile@cocos2d@@YAHPAX0I@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall myproject::ZipArchive::UnzipFileTo(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,bool)" (?UnzipFileTo@ZipArchive@myproject@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z)
1>ZipArchive.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl cocos2d::unzGoToNextFile(void *)" (__imp_?unzGoToNextFile@cocos2d@@YAHPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall myproject::ZipArchive::UnzipFileTo(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,bool)" (?UnzipFileTo@ZipArchive@myproject@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z)
1>ZipArchive.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl cocos2d::unzGetCurrentFileInfo(void *,struct cocos2d::unz_file_info_s *,char *,unsigned long,void *,unsigned long,char *,unsigned long)" (__imp_?unzGetCurrentFileInfo@cocos2d@@YAHPAXPAUunz_file_info_s@1@PADK0K2K@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall myproject::ZipArchive::UnzipFileTo(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,bool)" (?UnzipFileTo@ZipArchive@myproject@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z)
1>ZipArchive.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl cocos2d::unzOpenCurrentFilePassword(void *,char const *)" (__imp_?unzOpenCurrentFilePassword@cocos2d@@YAHPAXPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall myproject::ZipArchive::UnzipFileTo(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,bool)" (?UnzipFileTo@ZipArchive@myproject@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z)
1>ZipArchive.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl cocos2d::unzOpenCurrentFile(void *)" (__imp_?unzOpenCurrentFile@cocos2d@@YAHPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall myproject::ZipArchive::UnzipFileTo(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,bool)" (?UnzipFileTo@ZipArchive@myproject@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z)
1>ZipArchive.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl cocos2d::unzGoToFirstFile(void *)" (__imp_?unzGoToFirstFile@cocos2d@@YAHPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall myproject::ZipArchive::UnzipFileTo(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,bool)" (?UnzipFileTo@ZipArchive@myproject@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z)
1>ZipArchive.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl cocos2d::unzClose(void *)" (__imp_?unzClose@cocos2d@@YAHPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall myproject::ZipArchive::UnzipCloseFile(void)" (?UnzipCloseFile@ZipArchive@myproject@@QAE_NXZ)
```

I added libzlib.lib to my Additional Dependencies but it still gives me the errors. I am using VS2010

Comment: Have your version of the Cocos2d-x library been compiled with "unzip" support?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes there is unzip.h and unzip.cpp files cocos2dx project and it compiles without any error. And I have linked cocos2dx project to my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @PlasmaHH I know i need to link a library. That is why i linked libzlib.lib. But it is not working. My question is "Is there any other library I need to link?" or "Am I missing something here?"

Comment: @glo: Please read the answers in the mentioned question, they contain all you need.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I still don't get it. Am sorry but I still don't understand how to solve this specific issue.